# Change of phase from juvenile to adult in plants

Tags: botany

I tried googling this but couldn't get much information on this. Most of the articles were about induction of flowering.

I am more interested in knowing what factors influence the conversion of juvenile phase to adult phase in plants and not the induction of flowering.
Can a plant survive if it is artificially kept in a juvenile phase ?

Comment: there are no distinct developmental stages in most plants.. a plant which will grow up to become a big tree may still bear flowers when it is smaller. 

there is no juvenile phase in many animals too.. just that they are sexually immature.. only arthropods and some amphibians have a distinct larval stage which is very different from an adult.. they undergo metamorphosis whereas other organisms just grow and develop. you can stop the growth and also inhibit the sexual development but that would be just called as growth retardation

Comment: @WYSIWYG There ares some plants like Acacia koa which produce distinct types of leaves in juvenile and adult phase.

Comment: After a cursory reading on *Acacia koa* i gather that even the smaller plant bears the phyllodes along with the compound leaves. So i guess there is still no distinct `compound leaf only` stage. Just that perhaps the development of the compound leaf ceases after a stage. I am no expert in this topic so cant comment more. But if we go back the the original question - if an organism can be retained in a developmental stage: i guess it is possible to retain an animal in its larval stage by inhibiting metamorphosis. <note that metamorphosis is not just growth but a drastic change in lifestyle too>

Comment: I know a genetics professor that found the reason for the juvenile leaf into a adult, a gene (151) in the RNA. He is presently working on what factor that promotes this to happen.